# I initiated git in my Documents directory on my Mac

Tags: git, macos

Can I remove it?  in the Mac finder, this is a root directory, so I don't know how to get to where the .git file is to remove it.

Comment: Is there anything in the Git repository you want saved?  Are you using command line or Finder to try and remove it?  Assuming that there's nothing you need saved, and you're using a terminal, then `cd ~/Documents; rm -fr .git` will get rid of it for you.

Comment: Thanks for that...  no, I didn't have info in it, but it was showing all my files in the directory as not being staged (red)...  got a fix though...I do thank everyone for the help.  I used something similar to geogexsh's solution (thanks geogexsh!)..

Comment: This is what I used;                                                                                                      Open a Terminal (via Spotlight: press CMD + SPACE, type terminal and press Enter) and do this command: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1 && killall Finder, ...then followed with "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO && killall Finder". Seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 4):

in the Finder window, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, then dotfiles will show up, you could delete `.git` as you want, it might be `~/Documents/.git`.
just press it again to hide dot files again.

Comment: Thanks for the ⌘⇧. advice; that was very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Git keeps all of its files in the .git directory. Just remove that one.

`rm -rf ~/Documents/.git` will do it.